# Javascript DOM Console browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I tried many solution but it seems not working for me could anyone help me how to resolve my problem?

I want to change the GPS Fleet Management System value into `textarea`.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="caption">
  <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>GPS Fleet Managment System
</div>
<a href="#" id="change">Change</a>

var textbox = $("#caption");
var textarea = $("<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>");
$("#change").click(function () {
   textbox = textbox.value(textarea);
});
```

Comment: Change value attribute to html and lets see

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do man?

Comment: `textbox = textbox.value(textarea);` makes no sense. There is no value() in jQuery. And you are setting the value to be the .toString() of a jQuery object. And you are using an id selector, but your HTML code has a class.

Answer (score 2):

Change `value` to `html`, add `e.preventDefault()` and change the `#caption` selector to `.caption`:

```
var textbox = $(".caption");
var textarea = $("<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>");
$("#change").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    textbox.html(textarea);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be:

```js
$(function () {
  var textbox = $("#caption");
  var textarea = $("<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>");

  $("#change").click(function (e) {
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('caption')[0].childNodes[2];
    document.getElementsByClassName('caption')[0].replaceChild(textarea[0], ele);

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="caption">
    <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>GPS Fleet Managment System
</div>
<a href="#" id="change">Change</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default click event,to get the textarea value use `textarea.val();`

```
var textbox = $(".caption");
var textarea = $("<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>");
$("#change").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(textarea.val());
        //to add the textare to the page use append() or html()
       textbox.append(textarea); 
});
```

Comment: don't think he knows what he wants

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the div with a textarea, use http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/. Your `var textbox = $("#caption");` should be `.caption` since your element contains a class of caption, not an ID.

```
textbox.replaceWith(textarea);
```